# One of my two Apexcharts series doesn't auto-scale on Y-Axis

Tags: apexcharts

I have trouble to scale Y-axis on Apexcharts using JS.

I used this codepen :[Codepen](https://codepen.io/junedchhipa/pen/zmbGPG)    `Check codepen`

from Apexcharts website for multiple axis : [Apexcharts Website](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/multiple-yaxis-scales/)

I past my datas like :

SeriesA :

{x: '2020-04-21 00:06:24' ,y: 1009.07},{x: '2020-04-21 00:16:26' ,y: 1009.12},{x: '2020-04-21 00:26:28' ,y: 1009.04},{x: '2020-04-21 00:36:30' ,y: 1008.94},{x: '2020-04-21 00:46:32' ,y: 1009.09},{x: '2020-04-21 00:56:35' ,y: 1009.11},{x: '2020-04-21 01:06:37' ,y: 1009.29},{x: '2020-04-21 01:16:39' ,y: 1009.29},{x: '2020-04-21 01:26:41' ,y: 1009.16},{x: '2020-04-21 01:36:43' ,y: 1009.14},{x: '2020-04-21 01:46:45' ,y: 1009.18},{x: '2020-04-21 01:56:47' ,y: 1009.13},{x: '2020-04-21 02:06:49' ,y: 1009.06},{x: '2020-04-21 02:16:51' ,y: 1009.12},{x: '2020-04-21 02:26:53' ,y: 1009.07},{x: '2020-04-21 02:36:55' ,y: 1008.86},{x: '2020-04-21 02:46:57' ,y: 1008.77}

SeriesB:

{x: '2020-04-21 00:06:24' ,y: 13.86},{x: '2020-04-21 00:16:26' ,y: 13.85},{x: '2020-04-21 00:26:28' ,y: 13.87},{x: '2020-04-21 00:36:30' ,y: 13.68},{x: '2020-04-21 00:46:32' ,y: 13.84},{x: '2020-04-21 00:56:35' ,y: 13.91},{x: '2020-04-21 01:06:37' ,y: 13.87},{x: '2020-04-21 01:16:39' ,y: 13.84},{x: '2020-04-21 01:26:41' ,y: 13.75},{x: '2020-04-21 01:36:43' ,y: 13.56},{x: '2020-04-21 01:46:45' ,y: 13.48},{x: '2020-04-21 01:56:47' ,y: 13.54},{x: '2020-04-21 02:06:49' ,y: 13.54},{x: '2020-04-21 02:16:51' ,y: 13.5},{x: '2020-04-21 02:26:53' ,y: 13.31},{x: '2020-04-21 02:36:55' ,y: 13.44},{x: '2020-04-21 02:46:57' ,y: 13.32}

And I got the same behavior than on my website.
Series A are not scaled from min to max.

Does anyone has a solution please ?

Thank you.